# Regex to match "here strings" in PowerShell code

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm looking for a regex to match here strings in PowerShell `@'...'@` and `@"..."@` are [here strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules#here-strings)

Rules:

1. Always new line is followed after start(`@'` or `@"`)
2. There's no character after end (`'@` or `"@`), it always is at the line start, however more text can follow it up
3. The outer `@' .. '@` may include an inner `@" "@` but in this case the outer will be matched.

**Examples**

1. Example where outer (including `hello`) will be matched

```
$MyString = @"
hello
@'
'@
bye
"@
```

2. Other example where outer (including `hello`) will be matched

```
$MyString = @'
hello
@"
"@
bye
'@
```

3. Example from Microsoft

```
$page = [XML] @"
    <command:command xmlns:maml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/2004/10"
    xmlns:command="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/command/2004/10" 
    xmlns:dev="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/2004/10">
    <command:details>
            <command:name>
                   Format-Table
            </command:name>
            <maml:description>
                <maml:para>Formats the output as a table.</maml:para>
            </maml:description>
            <command:verb>format</command:verb>
            <command:noun>table</command:noun>
            <dev:version></dev:version>
    </command:details>
    ...
    </command:command>
"@
```

I'd appreciate any help. I'm trying solve inlining for better PowerShell templating support to [privacy.sexy](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy) so your help will be scaled to more in community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex solution, such as, for example,

```
"@(""|')\r?\n[\s\S]*?\r?\n\1@(?=\r?\n|$)"
```

or

```
"(?ms)@(""|')\r?$.*?^\1@(?=\r?$)"
```

may be good enough, although there is the potential for false matches.

For example, there is no actual here-string in the following valid Powershell code, but the regex above will produce a match.

```
$MyString = "Definitely @'
not a
'@
here-string
"
```

Comment: Another potential source of false positives are here-strings commented out via `<# ... #>`. Ultimately, only the language parser works robustly. As an aside: A good habit to form in PowerShell is to use _single_-quoted (verbatim) string literals (`'...'`) for regexes, so as to avoid confusion between what PowerShell's expandable strings (`"..."`) interpolate up front vs. what the .NET regex engine ends up seeing.

Comment: I think your answer was great @mklement0 and thank you for your explanation with all valid points/examples. I believe the information will provide good solution and insights to many that come here. But I'd trade robustness for a custom parser, as the parser in my case is written in another language (JavaScript). And simplicity (RegEx instead of a lot more complicated logic) is preferred.

Comment: None of the solutions match anything: regex101.com/r/u1HVEP/1, but thanks for the idea. \1 is great!

Comment: @U.Bulle Sorry, I had the second @ coming before the closing quote. Now corrected. Note that the above are for use in Powershell and thus the double quote is escaped with a double quote. Without the escaping we have e.g. `(?ms)@("|')\r?$.*?^\1@(?=\r?$)`.  [Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/P67D6C/1).

Answer (score 6):

You're better off **using PowerShell's language parser**, [`System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser), rather than a regex-based solution.<sup>[1]</sup>

I'm assuming you're always interested in the *outer* here-string, not one that happens to be nested inside another.

Assuming a file `file.ps1` with the following verbatim content:

```sh
$MyString1 = @'
hello
@"
"@
bye
'@

$MyString2 = @"
hello
@'
'@
bye
"@
```

The following command:

```sh
$ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput(
  (Get-Content -Raw file.ps1), 
  [ref] $null,
  [ref] $null
)

$ast.FindAll(
  { 
    $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.StringConstantExpressionAst] -and
      $args[0].StringConstantType -in 'SingleQuotedHereString', 'DoubleQuotedHereString' 
  },
  $true
) | Format-Table StringConstantType, Value -Wrap
```

outputs:

```
    StringConstantType Value
    ------------------ -----
SingleQuotedHereString hello
                       @"
                       "@
                       bye
DoubleQuotedHereString hello
                       @'
                       '@
                       bye
```

---

<sup>[1] A regex-based solution can yield *false positives*, which are virtually impossible to avoid. See [MikeM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69063505/45375) for an example; another one are here-strings that happen to be *commented out* via `<# ... #>`</sup>